# make a action call where number from database

Tags: android, phone-call

I have created an app that uses a phone call but I get a problem where when the button click does not happen anything, I save the number in a database. thisi is my code :

```
                final TextView txt_alamat = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_alamat);
            txt_alamat.setText(listData.get(position).getno_telp());
            nomor = String.format("tel :", txt_alamat.getText().toString().trim());

            Button btn_call = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_telpon);
            btn_call.setText(listData.get(position).getno_telp());
            btn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent TelpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Uri.parse("tel :"+nomor))));
                    TelpIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Telp_guru_Activity.this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    } else  {
                        Log.e(TAG,"error");
                    }
                    startActivity(TelpIntent);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's probably because you added a white space in "*tel_:*" Please remove and try again

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
            .setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + nomor)));
```

Comment: Still error i already remove space between "tel" bur isn't working to

Answer (score 0):

Pass number directly from DB. No need to write,

```
nomor = String.format("tel :", txt_alamat.getText().toString().trim());
```

Try to parse Uri in setData(),

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + nomor));

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Make sure that you are getting telephone number from DB.

Comment: Still error i already remove nomor = String.format("tel :", txt_alamat.getText().toString().trim()); but isn't working to

Comment: When I click button call on my logcat display "AudioALSAPlhandlerbas : - getHardwareBufferinfo pcm.............."

Comment: comment  checking permission code temporarily. and check again